# Read value of environment variables in makefile

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

Some of my environment variables are not showing up if I try to access them from in a makefile. My application creates an environment variable MACHTYPE with a value say "DELLMACHINE". 
I want to print this value using echo command in make files. Here is the code

```
@echo $(MACHTYPE)
```

Upon executing the above command empty string is getting displayed.

Interestingly, other environment variables such as PATH work fine, but MACHTYPE show up as the empty string. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: tip: in these cases I always use the `--warn` make parameter (short for `--warn-undefined-variables`).

Answer (score 5):

It's because you haven't exported the variable from your shell.  A normal shell variable is only in effect for that shell and not passed to any programs that the shell starts (like make).

If you want the variable to be added to the environment and passed to programs, you have to `export` it; run this in your shell or add it to your shell init file:

```
export MACHTYPE=DELLMACHINE
```

or else you can do it in two steps if you prefer:

```
MACHTYPE=DELLMACHINE

export MACHTYPE
```

Then, run `make` and you'll see the settings.

Answer (score -2):

`make` can give variables from cmd line.

Makefile

```
all:
    @echo $(MACHTYPE)
```

Then run 
`make MACHTYPE=DELLMACHINE`.